# Why must I use UserControl.MousePointer instead of Me.MousePointer?

Tags: vb6

In VB6 on a UserControl, I must use `UserControl.MousePointer = vbDefault` instead of `Me.MousePointer = vbDefault`. I can use `Me.MousePointer` on a Form (and `Form.MousePointer` doesn't work).

Why must I use `UserControl.MousePointer` instead of `Me.MousePointer`?

I mean literally the text "UserControl", not `UserControl` as the placeholder for another control name.

Comment: Is the `Me` literal defined at all in a UserControl?

Comment: Me specifically refers to the current form.  I believe there is also a Screen.MousePointer as well, but I could be wrong on that.  Each one specifically controls the mousepointer on the corresponding level.  Your control.MousePointer would over-ride the me (form) MousePointer, which overrides the screen MousePointer.  If your user control is a textbox, you may wish the cursor to change to a text pointer as the cursor moves over it, but back to the form's default as it leaves, etc.  Is this what you're asking?

Comment: Not quite. I'm creating a UserControl ocx but to set the MousePointer (and some other properties too) instead of doing Me.SomeProperty, for some properties (like MousePointer), I have to do UserControl.SomeProperty. I mean literally 'UserControl', not the name of a control but the actual literal text 'UserControl'. But if I create a Form, then I don't do Form.MousePointer, I do Me.MousePointer (Me being the Form object). On the UserControl object I'm creating, Me is the UserControl so I'm expecting to be able to do Me.MousePointer, but I can't and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. It turns out that since a UserControl is an ActiveX control, VB6 does some magic for you. With a Form control, it's not an ActiveX control which is why the MousePointer property is accessible via Me, like you'd expect.

For UserControl's, the UserControl control you create in VB6 sits on another control - the ActiveX control. That ActiveX control is accessible via UserControl. Something like this:

```
class ActiveXControl
{
    int MousePointer;
    VBUserControl control;
}
class VBUserControl
{
}
class YourUserControl : VBUserControl
{
    ActiveXControl UserControl;
    // we must use UserControl.MousePointer
}
```

but for a Form, it's more like this:

```
class Form
{
    int MousePointer;
}
class YourForm : Form
{
    // we actually inherit from Form so we use Me.MousePointer
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Me` isn't what you seem to think it is.  It is a reference to the current instance of the module you use it in, not "magic."

To get what you want you must add this property to the default interface of your UserControl, e.g.:

```
Option Explicit

Public Property Get MousePointer() As MousePointerConstants
    MousePointer = UserControl.MousePointer
End Property

Public Sub Test()
    MsgBox Me.MousePointer
End Sub
```

In VB6 Forms are a little different, probably as a holdover from 16-bit VB to make porting old code easier.  These always seem to inherit from a hidden interface.  This is defined in a type library you don't have access to since Microsoft did not release it as part of VB6.  Attempting to query it typically comes up with an error like:

> Cannot jump to 'MousePointer' because it is in the library 'Unknown10' which is not currently referenced

From this alone it seems likely that using `Me` always carries a small performance penalty.  Instead of going directly to the module's procedures it appears to me that you are going through its default COM interface.

You'd have to inspect the compiled code to determine whether there is a performance penalty, and if so how much.  I don't see this documented so otherwise we are just guessing about it.

In any case there is little reason to *ever* use `Me` unless you must in order to qualify something.

Crummy example but:

```
Option Explicit

Private mCharm As Long

Public Property Get Charm() As Long
    Charm = mCharm
End Property

Public Property Let Charm(ByVal RHS As Long)
    mCharm = RHS
    'Maybe we do more here such as update the user interface or some
    'other things.
End Property

Public Sub GetLucky(ByVal Charm As Long)
    'Do some stuff.
    Charm = Charm + Int(Rnd() * 50000)
    'etc.
    Me.Charm = Charm 'Here we use Me so we can assign to the property Charm.
End Sub
```

That's really about the only legitimate use for `Me` anyway: scoping to the desired namespace.  Relying on it because in typing it brings up IntelliSense is just lazy.

If anything *Forms* are "broken" not UserControls.